# Read a large file in chunks with a shared buffer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to read a 5GB file. Wondering if it's possible in dart to read a file in chunks, most importantly, each chunk is filled in a shared buffer for less memory pressure (we intend to run this app on mobile). Something like this:

```dart
// Creates a 200MB buffer.
var buffer = Uint8List(200 * 1024 * 1024);
while (<not EOF>) {
  var readCount = await file.fillBuffer(buffer);
  // Use the buffer.
}
```

I can do this pretty easily in C++/C#.

Comment: use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/openRead.html and study `Stream` API docs on how to process chunks of data

Comment: Or use [`File.open`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/open.html)/[`File.openSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/openSync.html) to get a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile-class.html).  That provides an API that's probably closer to what you're used to.